# When i call ajax there url wrong why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a one Edit.cshtml page and there is 1 partial template call. in that template I make an ajax call and my controller is home and action name is savedata

ajax function

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "CountryZone/SaveData",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: selectedID, id: id },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success");


        },
        error: function (result) {
            data.str = null;
            alert("Error");


        },
    });
```

controller:--

```
public ActionResult Savedata(string data, int CountryZoneId)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

now when my ajax call is going

there is url wrong :--- url is Home/edit/Home/Savedata instead of this there is only Home/SaveData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to hardcode urls in MVC application.

Change this line:

```
url: "CountryZone/SaveData",
```

To this:

```
url: "/CountryZone/SaveData",
```

I suggest at least using `Url.Action` in the view and storing it in the js variable.

Comment: Thank you for advice can you tell me good idea for Urls in mvc Application.?

Comment: @Vinit_Patel `Amit Agrawal` solution will work in `*.cshtml`, but won't work in separate `*.js` file, so I prefer storing urls in view, and then use them is js code. Like this: `var myUrl = '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")'`

Comment: @Vinit_Patel This guarantees that after changing routes all your code will work without any changes, also if your application won't be on root domain level. Like this: mydomain.com/level/mysite

Answer (score 1):

Use standard MVC code as below:

```
  url: '@Url.Action("SaveData","CountryZone")',
```

Full Code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveData","CountryZone")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: selectedID, CountryZoneId: id },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success");


        },
        error: function (result) {
            data.str = null;
            alert("Error");


        },
    });

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Savedata(string data, int CountryZoneId)
    {
        return null;
    }
```